# Can a quiet zip still show warnings for missing files?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zip

I often use `zip` with the `-q` flag (actually `-r -q`) for a quiet operation at the command line. Routinely I also then unzip each file I create, and check by eye whether the contents look correct; before I send the file on.

Without `-q` there is too much information; however in this case warnings are issued in situations I care about. For example, without `-q` missing files or directories are reported. An example is shown below.

```
$ touch readme1.md
$ zip test.zip readme1.md readme2.md 
    zip warning: name not matched: readme2.md
  adding: readme1.md (stored 0%)
```

Is there a flag or simple method which will mainly keep `zip` quiet, but still show warnings (as above) for missing files?

Comment: Maybe you can create a logfile with `-lf` option. It has some additional infos at the top and bottom, but at least it doesn't show all the regularly compressed files.

Comment: I am not sure if the shell script is simple method or not. You may verify the file exist and print warning before zip in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do that with `zip` (other than logging as suggested and parsing/reading the logs afterwards) but `p7zip` has the [`-bs` option](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm) that allows you to disable certain streams e.g.

```
7z a -bso0 -bsp0 test.zip readme1.md readme2.md
```

disables `stdout` and `progress` but prints warnings/errors, if any:

```
WARNING: No such file or directory
readme2.md


Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

readme2.md : No such file or directory
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1
```